# Firebase Authentication for Ionic 3 app - cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase Authentication within my Ionic 3 app.

I have followed the helpful tutorial at https://medium.com/appseed-io/integrating-firebase-password-and-google-authentication-into-your-ionic-3-app-2421cee32db9 and it pretty much seems to work.

I am seeing what appears to be an intermittent error when first opening the app:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((onfulfilled?: (value: void) => TResult1 | PromiseLike

This relates to `src/pages/login/login.ts` on line 52. I'll paste `login.ts` in its entirety below but the problematic line is `this.auth.signInWithGoogle()`

[image: error message]

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { SignupPage } from '../signup/signup';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    loginError: string;

    constructor(
        private navCtrl: NavController,
        private auth: AuthService,
        fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.loginForm = fb.group({
            email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
            password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])]
        });
    }

    login() {
        let data = this.loginForm.value;

        if (!data.email) {
            return;
        }

        let credentials = {
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password
        };
        this.auth.signInWithEmail(credentials)
            .then(
                () => this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage),
                error => this.loginError = error.message
            );
    }   

    signup(){
      this.navCtrl.push(SignupPage);
    }   

    loginWithGoogle() {
      this.auth.signInWithGoogle()
        .then(
          () => this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage),
          error => console.log(error.message)
        );
    }       

}
```

In case it helps, here is my `auth.service.ts` file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import AuthProvider = firebase.auth.AuthProvider;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private user: firebase.User;

    constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
            this.user = user;
        });
    }

    signInWithEmail(credentials) {
        console.log('Sign in with email');
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email,
             credentials.password);
    }

    signUp(credentials) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password);
    }

    get authenticated(): boolean {
      return this.user !== null;
    }   

    getEmail() {
      return this.user && this.user.email;
    }   

    getUid() {
      return this.user && this.user.uid;
    }   

    signOut(): Promise<void> {
      return this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    }   

    signInWithGoogle() {
            console.log('Sign in with google');
            return this.oauthSignIn(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    }

    private oauthSignIn(provider: AuthProvider) {
        if (!(<any>window).cordova) {
            return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
        } else {
            return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider)
            .then(() => {
                return this.afAuth.auth.getRedirectResult().then( result => {
                    // This gives you a Google Access Token.
                    // You can use it to access the Google API.
                    let token = result.credential.accessToken;
                    // The signed-in user info.
                    let user = result.user;
                    console.log(token, user);
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    // Handle Errors here.
                    alert(error.message);
                });
            });
        }
    }   

}
```

Here is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@ultimate/ngxerrors": "^1.4.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.2",
    "cordova-ios": "5.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.9.4",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try checking if the cause of the issue at `new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()` ?

Comment: Hi - do you have any advice for the best way to debug this line?

Comment: Instead of `return this.oauthSignIn(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());`, do:

`const xx = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
return this.oauthSignIn(xx);`

If the error happen on the line xx, then you know its that line that is causing the issue

Comment: Understood. The error relates to line 52 of login.ts - this.auth.signInWithGoogle(). I have updated my question showing a screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

> I have updated my answer based on your updated question and comment.

Based on your `package.json` you are trying to build a Hybrid Mobile App (i.e., it uses Cordova/PhoneGap) that targets iOS using Ionic 3.

Take a look at the Ionic v3 GitHub [repo](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3), it looks like the latest [v3](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/blob/v3.9.5/package.json) is "3.9.5".  And, the latest Ionic App Scripts is "3.2.2".

Ionic v3 works with Angular "5.0.3" and TypeScript ">=2.4.2 <2.5".
The version in your `package.json` -> "typescript": "~2.6.2" is too new for Ionic 3.

You also need to choose a version of angularfire2 that will work with Ionic v3 and Angular "5.0.3". For example: "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6".

To fix the TypeScript error try adding types to each of the AuthService's methods, each methods parameters and don't forget to add a return type as well.

For example:

```
    public signInWithEmail(credentials: Credentials) Promise<any> {

        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email,
             credentials.password);
    }
```

I have built a [PWA](https://craftbeer.org.au) using Ionic 3, Angular 5 and angularfire2 (that uses Firestore, Firebase Storage and Firebase Auth). And, its not easy to get the dependencies just right :)

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Brew",
  "description": "Brew: The Craft Beer App",
  "version": "1.0.0-beta.2",
  "author": "Rob Ferguson",
  "homepage": "https://craftbeer.org.au",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "dev": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "ios:dev": "ionic-app-scripts serve --platform=ios",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build && npm run ngsw-config && npm run ngsw-copy",
    "ios:build": "ionic-app-scripts build --platform=ios && npm run ngsw-config && npm run ngsw-copy",
    "test": "ng test --config ./config/karma.conf.js",
    "test-ci": "ng test --config ./config/karma.conf.js --watch=false --code-coverage",
    "test-coverage": "ng test --config ./config/karma.conf.js --code-coverage",
    "e2e": "npm run e2e-update && npm run e2e-test",
    "e2e-test": "protractor ./config/protractor.conf.js",
    "e2e-update": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build && npm run ngsw-config && npm run ngsw-copy",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "ng": "ng",
    "ngsw-config": "node_modules/.bin/ngsw-config www src/ngsw-config.json",
    "ngsw-copy": "cp node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js www/",
    "version-update": "node ./update-build-version.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "5.2.10",
    "@firebase/app": "0.1.10",
    "@ngx-pwa/local-storage": "5.3.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6",
    "firebase": "4.13.1",
    "fix-orientation": "0.0.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ngx-pipes": "^2.3.5",
    "promise-polyfill": "7.1.2",
    "raven-js": "^3.27.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.4",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-angular/schematics": "^1.1.4",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "purify-css": "^1.2.5",
    "replace-in-file": "^3.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": ">=2.4.2 <2.5"
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js",
    "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js",
    "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with my package.json. As for adding types, presumably I need to add a type to auth.service.ts on signInWithGoogle()  but I don't know what the type should be?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your function returns `Promise<I don't Know> | void`. Since you return different promise types from your `then` you got

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

error.

`setRoot(pageOrViewCtrl, params, opts, done)` => returns Promise

`console.log(error.message)` => returns void

```
loginWithGoogle() {
      this.auth.signInWithGoogle()
        .then(
          () => this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage), // here you return a promise
          error => console.log(error.message) // here you return a void 
        );
    }
```

The solution to your problem is curly braces. ;)

> If you omit the braces, the arrow function has a concise body, which consists solely of a single expression whose result will implicitly become the return value of the function.

`this.auth.signInWithGoogle()
      .then(
         () => {this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage)},
         error => { console.log(error.message)} 
  );`

hope this works. here are some references.

1. [call signature issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327264/cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature-for-function-retur)
2. [curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440265/curly-brackets-in-arrow-functions)

hope it helps.